# Display random images from folder with PHP without duplicates

Tags: php, image, random, duplicates

I am trying to display a certain amount of random images from one directory on my website without displaying duplicates.

I found this question: [Display 2 random pictures PHP with no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093705/display-2-random-pictures-php-with-no-duplicates) which partially answers my problem:

```
<?php
$pics = array('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg');
$images = array_rand($pics, 2);
?>

<img src="images/<?php echo $pics[$images[0]]; ?>" />
<img src="images/<?php echo $pics[$images[1]]; ?>" />
```

The problem I have is that the images are uploaded to the folder with completely different/random names such as 1a2265fg65444.jpg 55v4423097ww6.jpg etc, so I can't manually add them to the $pics array. I need to somehow scrape the directory for *.jpg and have the array generated automatically

I did try Michal Robinsons answer on [Show Random images from a folder without repeating using JS or PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358090/show-random-images-from-a-folder-without-repeating-using-js-or-php) but couldn't get it to print anything for some reason:

```
$all_images = glob("/images/photos/{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
shuffle($all_images); 
$images = array();
foreach ($all_images as $index => $image) {
     if ($index == 15) break;  // Only print 15 images
     $image_name = basename($image);
     echo "<img src='/images/photos/{$image_name}' />";
}
```

Perhaps I'm missing something?

Any pointers would be simply awesome.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure `/public/directory/{$image_name}` is the right path?

Comment: Hi Arkadi, thanks for the reply. I did use my own image path on my website, the code in my question is just taken from the referenced posts.

Comment: @FredBentley Can you provide more details regarding your setup? Where is you upload dir? Maybe an `ls` or a `dir` showing image names and paths?

Comment: write `print_r($all_images); die();` before `foreach` and check what's printed

Comment: I updated the 2nd block of code above to show that my images are in /images/photos/ there are 70 images in there at present so for example https://www.mywebsite.com/images/photos/55v4423097ww6.jpg is one.  I tried your suggestion Arkadi, but it seems to kill the script.  Could it be something to do with $images = array();  not being referenced again in the code?  Should $image later in the code also be $images?

Comment: Arkadi, I see what your line of code does. It doesn't show anything  :/

Comment: Fixed, I changed: glob("/images/photos/  to   glob("images/photos/

Comment: Thank you for your help guys  :)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$scan = scandir("/images/photos/");
shuffle($scan);
$r = rand(2, count($scan)); // maybe (count($scan) - 1)
printf("<img src='/images/photos/%s' />", basename($scan[$r]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aron, but I managed to fix it by changing:

```
glob("/images/photos/ to 
glob("images/photos/
```

To complicate things further though, I just realized I need to show 1 image from a 1st folder followed by another image from a 2nd folder, and repeat this about 5 times, still without showing any duplicate  :/ This is as far as I have got, but seem to be digging a bigger hole that doesn't work, as I'm stuck at the foreach...:

```
$all_images1 = glob("images/photos/{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
$all_images2 = glob("images/photos1/{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
shuffle($all_images1); 
shuffle($all_images2); 
$images1 = array();
$images2 = array();
$class = 1; 
foreach ($all_images1 as $index1 => $image1) {
if ($index1 == 10) break;  // Only print 15 images
$image_name1 = basename($image1);
echo "<img src='/images/photos/{$image_name1}' class='image".$class++."' /> <img src='/images/photos1/{$image_name2}' class='image".$class++."' />";
}
```

Am I going in the wrong direction to do this?

Thanks Ted